# Facebook Deferred Deeplinking is always returning url is nil in iOS (14+)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, deferred-deep-linking

I'm trying to calling the Deferred Deeplinking of Facebook with the function:

```
 AppLinkUtility.fetchDeferredAppLink { (url, error) in ... }
```

I am taking the user permission consent alert before calling the deferred deeplinking method

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

```
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { (status) in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                // Tracking authorization dialog was shown
                // and we are authorized
                print("Authorized")
                // Now that we are authorized we can get the IDFA
                print(ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.fetchDeferredDeeplink()
                }
            case .denied:
                // Tracking authorization dialog was
                // shown and permission is denied
                print("Denied")
            case .notDetermined:
                // Tracking authorization dialog has not been shown
                print("Not Determined")
            case .restricted:
                print("Restricted")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
   func fetchDeferredDeeplink(){
    Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
    Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
    Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true
    ApplicationDelegate.shared.initializeSDK()
    AppLinkUtility.fetchDeferredAppLink { (url, error) in
        if let url = url {
            print(url)

        }
        print(error as Any)
    }

}
```

Add Below keys to info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>**Your URL Scheme** </string>
                <string>**Your FB app id** </string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

The result is always the same, url = nil. I have tried all the ways and followed many blogs

I'm using:

Xcode Version: 12.4
Swift Version: 5.2
Installation Facebook SDK: 14.1.0